# Error on creating style object in IE with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

This code works well in FF but throws an error in IE v9:

```js
var iconStyle = dojo.create('style', { 
   innerHTML:  '.ZMyToolbarBtn { background-image: url("../resources/toolbar/my.png"); }' 
});
dojo.doc.body.appendChild(iconStyle);
```

Comment: And whats the error you're seeing in IE? Not every one has IE 9 at hand.

Comment: what version of dojo are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a cross browser version, you'd better use `dojox/html/styles`

```
dojoxStyles.insertCssRule('ZMyToolbarBtn', 'background-image: url("../resources/toolbar/my.png");')
```